# Why the following regular expression does not match the string?

Tags: c#, regex

The expression is `@"\{text:(?<text>[.]+),url:(?<url>[.]+)\}"`
and the string is `{text:frbs,url:http://koo.gk/xM6J}`

I am clueless about where does this go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the character class around dot. `[.]+` matches one or more literal dot characters. But `.+` matches any character one or more times.

```
@"\{text:(?<text>.+),url:(?<url>.+)\}"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vR8dL3/1)

Comment: Trying right now and will let you know immediately.

Comment: It works. Thank you. I will accept the answer in 8 minutes.